# IF ISNUMBER SEARCH - distinguish between similar text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Hoping someone smarter than myself can help:

Column F contains either of the words below, and I want to excel formula to return whether the data is "White" or "Pink"

- Ban
- Bandearg

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ban",F2)),"White",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bandearg",F2)),"Pink")`

The problem is that everything returns as "White" as it is finding "Ban" in both. Presume I am using the formula wrong.

Bán is the Irish for White and Bándearg is the Irish for Pink!

Comment: Swap them around? `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bandearg",F2)),"Pink",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ban",F2)),"White"`

Comment: @JvdV: Could you explain what 'ISNUMBER' is used for here?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I tried to explain it below. Hopefully it does help. What does help is just to evaluate the formula using the build-in function =)

Comment: @JvdV: I usually use IFERROR or IF(ISERROR...). Which is better i.e. faster, more correct?

Comment: @VBasic2008, you might want to test efficiency on a large set of data, however a personal preference would always be to avoid `IFERROR` and `IF(ISERROR)` where possible since these functions hide all possible errors making you unaware of what could be wrong with your data. It comes in handy at times for sure, but in this case I would stay away from it.

Comment: Are those words the only thing in the cell, or might it be part of a multiword string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, simply swap them around:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bandearg",F2)),"Pink",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ban",F2)),"White"))
```

---

`ISNUMBER` checks wheather or not `SEARCH` returns a number (meaning the substring is found starting at that index/position) or an `#VALUE` error. In the first case, it will return `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE` continueing with the second nested `IF`. Note that this formula will return `FALSE` if "Ban" isn't found at all.

Comment: This is so simple and solved it perfectly - thank you! 
And thank you all for your responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just simply add a space behind the criteria and the result value, and your formula become :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ban ",F2&" ")),"White",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bandearg ",F2&" ")),"Pink"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If those words are all that the cell contains, you can simply use:

```
=IF(A1="Ban","White",IF(A1="Bandearg","Pink",""))
```

or, in later versions of Excel (2019+  or O365):

```
=IFS(A1="Ban","White",A1="Bandearg","Pink",TRUE,"")
```